# Validate few emails in one textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need validate few email, which user type with keypress email. The emails must separate with only comma or backspace and comma. I have such validate function for email

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(email);
}
```

I think i must write something like this, but i don't know what i must do next

```
$('textbox').on('keypress change keyupp', function(e){
      if(e.keyCode == 32 || e.keyCode == 188){
      }
});
```

Comment: You would need to split the value of the textbox by the space/comma and then loop through each entered email address and validate it's format. However, I would say that this isn't a great UI pattern to use as the user will not necessarily be able to tell which email is invalid, or where it is in the textbox. It would be  much better to add a new textbox per email address and allow single entry only.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank u for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your event handler to

```
$('textbox').on('keypress change keyupp', function(e){
      var badEmails = this.value.split(",").filter(function(val){return !validateEmail(val) });
      if( badEmails.length  > 0 ) )
      {
        return false;
      }
});
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes missed out on that, made the changes now

Comment: You want `return !validateEmail(val)`